# Scala: "Incompatible type" error when extending Map via a trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I have a class that is basically a `Map` with a few extra methods. I implemented it by wrapping a regular `Map`, like so:

```scala
class IntIntMap private (
  val delegate: Map[Int, Int]
) extends Map[Int, Int] with MapLike[Int, Int, IntIntMap] {
  def extraMethod: Unit = println("Test!")
  // Method overrides from MapLike
  // CanBuildFrom, implicit conversions, etc. in the companion object
}
```

This works fine; however, later on I found out that I need two different classes for the same data: a map-like one for assembling the data and an optimized version for accessing it. I figured I could factor the extra part out into a trait:

```scala
trait IntIntTrait extends Map[Int, Int] with MapLike[Int, Int, IntIntTrait] {
  def extraMethod: Unit
}

class IntIntMap private (
  val delegate: Map[Int, Int]
) extends IntIntTrait {
  override def extraMethod: Unit = println("Test!")
  // Method overrides from MapLike
  // CanBuildFrom, implicit conversions, etc. in the companion object
}

class OtherImplementation extends IntIntTrait { ... }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as I get the following error: `overriding method empty in trait MapLike of type => IntIntMap; method empty in trait Map of type => scala.collection.Map[Int, Int] has incompatible type`.

I tried moving the `MapLike` from the trait to the class, but it still results in the same error. I also tried to define it with `MapLike[Int, Int, Map[Int, Int]]`, which compiles, but then `filter`, etc. return `Map[Int, Int]`, not an `IntIntMap`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your first snippet doesn't work either.
Extending a `Map` like that is ... difficult. I probably *can* be done, but is almost certainly will be way too much of a complication for your purposes.

I would stick with implicit extension:

```
 object MapOps {
    implicit class IntIntMap(val delegate: Map[Int, Int]) extends AnyVal {
      def extraMethod: Unit = println("Test!")
    } 
 }
```

This adds `extraMethod` to any `Map[Int, Int]`:

```
   import MapOps._
   Map(1 -> 1).extraMethod
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the first snippet definitely works. And the reason why I need a trait (or something similar) is because I want to have another implementation, which won't be backed by a `Map`. So I need that one layer of abstraction.

Comment: If it is not backed my a map, it doesn't need to extend the map, does it?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want to / cannot change the whole hierarchy of classes and functions that refer to this class. Part of the code depends on it being a Map, but for other parts, it's _very_ suboptimal. So I figured I keep the "mapness" around, while changing the implementation seamlessly for the second part. This would be a very simple thing for all other programming languages I know: have an interface I, classes A and B that implement it, and replace each A with a B before the second part begins.

Comment: Can you make a scastie showing the first snippet compiling? Because as far as I can see, it [does not](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/V5ktUB9UQUGlqx2YY3wBug). And should not: the problem is not with the trait you are trying to add, but with trying to extend a `Map` with a _different_ `MapLike`

Comment: [There you are](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/peWlbzW5T2OTs5lhxRTKXg). We kind of both were right: it compiles, but then the automatic conversion after the `filter()` fails. If you replace `IntIntMap` with `Map[Int, Int]` as the third type argument to `MapLike`, everything works, provided we import `implicitConversions`. That is actually a good solution for the single class case, but I am not sure how to apply it to the trait-based setup.

Comment: I have +1'd your answer. It does not solve the problem unfortunately, but in the end I managed to cook up something using pimping (implicit extension), although it became more cumbersome than if I could have subclassed `Map` like I would have in other languages. Thanks for the idea!